# Closing one socket closes all of them, Java

Tags: java, sockets

I have a multi-thread chatroom that connects to one server. They all connect, login, and message independently of each other just fine, but when I log off with one of the clients (and the server does a socket.close() for that instance of the client) all clients are logged off. I looked at a bunch of other questions on stackoverflow before posting this, but none of them had the same issue as mine (that I found). Note: All the clients were running locally on my computer, 2+ of them, and that's how I encountered the bug. Could them being on the same IP (though everything is done on my localhost..) cause this to happen? Any help or insight as to what is causing this issue and how I could resolve it would be great. When the issue occurs it also outputs this to the console:

```
Socket: Socket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,port=4000,localport=55650]
```

Here is the code (how to recreate the bug is at the bottom):

**Server class:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.HashSet;

public class ChatServer {

private static final int PORT = 4000;
private static HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<String>();
private static HashSet<ObjectOutputStream> outputs = 
                               new HashSet<ObjectOutputStream>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    System.out.println("The chat server is running...");
    ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(PORT);

    while(true){
        new Handler(listener.accept()).start();
    }
}

private static class Handler extends Thread{
    private String name;
    private Socket socket;
    private ObjectInputStream in;
    private ObjectOutputStream out;
    private boolean loggedOut;

    public Handler(Socket socket){
        this.socket = socket;

    }

    public void run(){
        try {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            loggedOut = false;

            while(true){
                Message message = (Message) in.readObject();
                System.out.println("Server recieved login message!");
                if(message.getNumber() == 0){
                    name = message.getName();
                    synchronized(names){
                        if(!names.contains(name)){
                            names.add(name);
                            break;
                        }else{
                            Message nameTaken = new Message(null, 3);
                            sendMessage(out, nameTaken);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            synchronized(outputs){
                outputs.add(out);   
            }

            for(ObjectOutputStream output: outputs){
                Message response = new Message(name, name + " has logged on.", 0);
                sendMessage(output, response);
            }

            while(true){
                System.out.println("Waiting for message...");
                Message message = (Message) in.readObject();
                Message response = null;
                if(message.getNumber() == 1 && message.getMessage() != null){
                    response = new Message(message.getName(),
                                message.getMessage(), 1);
                }else if(message.getNumber() == 2){
                    response = new Message(message.getName(), message.getName() + 
                                         " has logged off.", 2);
                    loggedOut = true;
                }   
                for(ObjectOutputStream output: outputs){
                    sendMessage(output, response);
                }
                if(loggedOut) break;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(name != null) names.remove(name);
            if(out != null) outputs.remove(out);
            try{
                socket.close();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void sendMessage(ObjectOutputStream out, Message message){
        ObjectOutputStream outPutMessage = out;
        Message response = message;
        try {
            outPutMessage.writeObject(response);
            outPutMessage.flush();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Client class:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ChatClient extends JFrame {
private JTextField inputField;
private JTextField nameField;
private JTextArea textArea;
private JButton loginButton;
private JButton logoutButton;
private JButton connectButton;
private JScrollPane textScroll;
private JScrollPane listScroll;
private JPanel textPanel;
private JPanel connectPanel;
private JPanel listPanel;
private JPanel inputPanel;
private JPanel namePanel;
private JPanel inputAndDisplayPanel;
private JPanel listAndLogoutPanel;
private ArrayList<String> stringList;
private JList list;
private final int CELL_WIDTH = 100;
private ObjectOutputStream out;
private ObjectInputStream in;
private JFrame chatFrame;
private ChatClient client;
private String name;
private final int PORT = 4000;
private boolean needServerData;
private boolean loggedIn;
private boolean previouslyLoggedIn;
private String serverAddress = null;
private Socket socket = null;   

private void run() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
    needServerData = true;
    loggedIn = true;

    while(true){
        //Loops before a user is logged in, verifies that the host is usable
        while (socket == null) {
            if (needServerData) {
                try {
                    connectButton.setEnabled(false);
                    serverAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(client,
                            "Enter server address: ", "Server Address",
                            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                    if(serverAddress == null){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(client,
                                "Click 'Connect' to re-enter server address.",
                                    "Info", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                        needServerData = false;
                        connectButton.setEnabled(true);
                    }else if(serverAddress.equals("")){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(client,
                                "Invalid input! Enter a valid server address.", 
                               "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    }else {
                        socket = new Socket(serverAddress, PORT);
                        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                        in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                        loginButton.setEnabled(true);
                        logoutButton.setEnabled(false);
                        nameField.setEnabled(true); 
                        connectButton.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(client,
                            "Error: Unknown host!", "Error",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        }

        /*Loops after the user is logged in (will output to the textarea that that user logged in), 
         * reads in messages from server to append to the textarea and also determines if a user is 
         * logging out. Changes editable/enabled of buttons and text fields accordingly.
        */
        if(loggedIn) {
            Message message = (Message) in.readObject();
            if (message.getNumber() == 1) {
                textArea.append(message.getName() + ": "
                        + message.getMessage() + "\n");
            } else if (message.getNumber() == 0) {
                inputField.setEditable(true);
                textArea.append(message.getMessage() + "\n");
                loginButton.setEnabled(false);
                logoutButton.setEnabled(true);
            } else if (message.getNumber() == 2) {
                inputField.setText(null);
                inputField.setEditable(false);
                nameField.setText(null);
                nameField.setEnabled(false);
                connectButton.setEnabled(true);
                logoutButton.setEnabled(false);
                loggedIn = false;
                previouslyLoggedIn = true;
                textArea.append(message.getMessage() + "\n");
                System.out.println("Socket: " + socket);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(client,
                        "Error: That name is taken!", "Error",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }
}

private String getServerAddress(){
    return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(client, "Enter server address: ",
            "Server Address", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        ChatClient client = new ChatClient();
        try {
            client.run();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
}

public ChatClient(){
    //GUI Formatting Stuff
    inputField = new JTextField(30);
    nameField = new JTextField(10);
    textArea = new JTextArea(25, 30);
    loginButton = new JButton("Login");
    logoutButton = new JButton("Logout");
    connectButton = new JButton("Connect");
    textScroll = new JScrollPane(textArea,
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    textPanel = new JPanel();
    listPanel = new JPanel();
    inputPanel = new JPanel();
    namePanel = new JPanel();
    connectPanel = new JPanel();

    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textPanel.add(textScroll);

    stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    list = new JList(stringList.toArray());
    list.setFixedCellWidth(CELL_WIDTH);
    listScroll = new JScrollPane(list);
    listPanel.add(listScroll);
    listAndLogoutPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    listAndLogoutPanel.add(listPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    listAndLogoutPanel.add(logoutButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    listAndLogoutPanel.add(loginButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    inputField.setEditable(false);
    inputPanel.add(inputField);

    inputAndDisplayPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    inputAndDisplayPanel.add(textPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    inputAndDisplayPanel.add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    nameField.setEnabled(false);
    loginButton.setEnabled(false);
    logoutButton.setEnabled(false);
    namePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    namePanel.add(new JLabel("Name: "));
    namePanel.add(nameField);

    connectPanel.add(connectButton);
    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    topPanel.add(namePanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    topPanel.add(connectPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);

    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    centerPanel.add(inputAndDisplayPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    centerPanel.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    JPanel eastPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    eastPanel.add(listAndLogoutPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(eastPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    pack();
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    //Listeners
    loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ 
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            name = nameField.getText();
            if(name.trim().length() < 3 || name.length() > 15 || name == null){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(client,
                        "Error: Name must be between 3 and 15 characters long.", "Error",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                Message message = new Message(name, 0);
                try {
                    out.writeObject(message);
                    out.flush();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                loggedIn = true;
            }
        }
    });

    connectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            needServerData = true;
            if(previouslyLoggedIn) socket = null;
        }       
    }); 

    inputField.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Message message = new Message(name, inputField.getText(), 1);

            try {
                out.writeObject(message);
                out.flush();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            inputField.setText(null);
        }       
    }); 

    logoutButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            Message message = new Message(name, 2);
            try {
                out.writeObject(message);
                out.flush();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            inputField.setText(null);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**Message class:**

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Message implements Serializable{

private int number;
private String message;
private String name;

public Message(String name, int number){
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number; 
}

public Message(String name, String message, int number){
    this.message = message;
    this.number = number;
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean isLogin(){
    if(number == 0) return true;
    return false;
}

public boolean isMessage(){
    if(number == 1) return true;
    return false;
}

public boolean isLogout(){
    if(number == 2) return true;
    return false;
}

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

I know this is a big block of code and not that neatly documented/formatted, so I apologize for that. I'm just posting the whole thing so you can duplicate the problem by running the code in it's entirety. Additionally, ignore the JList as I haven't gotten to that yet since I encountered and haven't been able to resolve the logging off/socket issue. To recreate the bug, go through the following steps:

1. Run the Server class
2. Run a client class, enter "localhost" as the server address, then enter a name and click log-in
3. Run another client class and follow step 2
4. Click log-off on one of the client classes, and you'll see the other is also logged off.

Thanks in advance for any help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ChatClient class, you need to change the line

```
} else if (message.getNumber() == 2) {
```

to

```
} else if (message.getNumber() == 2 && message.getName().equals(name)) {
```

Because the way it is currently, each chat client receives the message that a client has been logged out, and each client is responding to that by logging out. You will need to handle the additional case afterwards that message.getNumber() == 2, because as it stands now you will assume that it means the name was taken.

Comment: Oh wow, I totally didn't even think of that being the cause of it! Stupid of me to have the number used to identify if someone has logged out to also display that said person had logged out to all other clients - total oversight. I guess I didn't look through it as thoroughly as I thought >.< Thanks a ton for looking that over and figuring that out! Much appreciated. And yeah, I added an additional case since it was defaulting to the name taken portion of the if/else block. Thanks!